# Problems with XAMPP and Wordpress Multiste

Tags: wordpress, xampp

Hi i have a huge problem wth XAMPP and would appreciate any help,

I've installed XAMPP on Windows 10 and followed the instructions here: [Moving WordPress Multisite from Live Server to Localhost Safely](http://www.aurodigo.com/2013/12/moving-wordpress-multisite-from-live-server-to-localhost-safely.html#comments).

After following the tutorial the main domain works. However the mapped domains and subdomains don't. 
I have a very complex Wordpress Multisite Network where i use three different topdomains on one install. All these topdomains also have their own subdirectories. Although they are all installed under the dtopdomain and visible in /sites directory.

Any advice on how to proceed in order to get this to work?

Comment: Adding a diagram of the directory structure would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Fencer and thanks for your response. This is how the structure looks like: 
TOPDOMAIN1.COM
↓
START.TOPDOMAIN2.COM
↓
START.TOPDOMAIN3.COM

Comment: Please edit your question with this including the surrounding folder structure above this.